# 2 divs, containing 2 divs each and responsive

Tags: html, css

@All:

I want to create a responsive structure of two divs which in turn contain two divs each as shown in the fig below.

[image: Divs During normal view]

Once the same turns responsive the structure should appear like:

[image: Responsive View of the Divs]

Please guide me in achieving the same.

Comment: till now what you have done ?

Comment: The answers below rely on fixed widths for the boxes. Do your boxes have equal and constant dimensions?

Comment: yes they have fixed dimensions but in %age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="big">
            <div class="small"></div>
             <div class="small"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="big">
             <div class="small"></div>
              <div class="small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the style

```
.container{
            width:600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .big{
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            float: left;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .small{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        @media(max-width:597px)
        {
            .container{
                width: 300px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: the container that you have created here is not having a height that shall enclose the remaining divs. Hence the problem is that when i populate the internal divs, the footer below actually goes and sticks to the container. How can i get rid of this problem. I have tried using "height: auto;" and "height: auto !important;"

Comment: Also i cannot keep the height specific. I need to keep the height variable, because responsive or not, the data inside the divs still keeps on changing. If i fix the height, of the container then i have a problem during responsive.

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/90knutoc/11/

Comment: i don;t know if i got your idea but i think your problem is that the footer does not stick to bottom of the page when the content is  small and it stick to the container which makes it looks in midel of the page ???? i believe the simplest way is to give the container min-height try it and let me know if it fixes your problem

Comment: you can also look for some thing called sticky footer

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. One of the simplest is to use `display: inline-block`. The content will then automatically wrap to fit the width of your browser. Try running this snippet, click "Full page", and resize your browser.

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:3px solid black;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  padding:4px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
div div {
  border-color: red;
  width:134px;
  height:136px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  HTML

```
 <div id="conatiner">
    <div id="div1">
      <div id="div11"></div>
      <div id="div12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <div id="div21"></div>
      <div id="div22"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and the css is

```
 #div1, #div2 {
   width:45%;
   min-width:200px;
   margin:1%;
   float:left;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }

 #div11, #div12, #div21, #div22 {
   display:inline-block;
   width:45%;
   min-width:50px;  // this width should 1/4th of the min-width of div1 and div2
   margin:1%;
   height:100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
```

here js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/90knutoc/9/